# How to compile OpenPACE for android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

could anyone help me to compile [OpenPACE](http://openpace.sourceforge.net/) for Android? Maybe the new Standalone Toolchain in NDK r5 is a good starting point, but i cant get things working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found a way using the new standalone toolchain included in NDK-r5 and newer.